# sorting of character variable on x axis of ggplot in R

Tags: sorting, ggplot2, character, x-axis

I am using ggplot for plotting the Systolic blood pressures on y axis for 7 patients present in my data. My x axis is the combination of name of the visit and the timepoint both pasted with the help of 'H'. For eg. C1D1PRE H7 meaning hour 7 of C1D1 visit. I want to sort x axis with respect to this variable.

Ideally x axis should show visits arranged in the order of Datetime when they occurred (Viz. SCR H15, C1D1PRE H8, C1D1PRE H13, C1D1HR2 H12), but when plotted for all subjects on the same graph, the visit order is getting disturbed.

my data (df) looks like below-

| Datetime | Visit | Visitnum | Patientnum | SBP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-07-20 15:04:00 | SCR H15 | 1 | 1 | 115 |
| 2018-09-04 13:30:00 | C1D1PRE H13 | 2 | 1 | 120 |
| 2021-08-31 08:20:00 | C1D1PRE H8 | 2 | 2 | 130 |
| 2021-09-06 12:36:00 | C1D1HR2 H12 | 3 | 3 | 127 |

The code that I am using-

```r
plotsv <- ggplot(df, x = reorder(df$Visit, df$Datetime), y = df$SBP, color = Patientnum, group= Patientnum) + 
    geom_point(shape = "square", size = 4) + 
    geom_line(linetype = "solid", size = 1)
```

This code works best when there is only one patient in the data. But not for all patients on the same graph. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid it's difficult to test what can work without a larger sample of your data. Would suggest you post a sample using `dput()` to output the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a DF based on the data you show in the pic. Please have a look to **Data** below.

Your code does not show any aesthetics `aes` in `ggplot`.
Please, have a look to the documentation.

I have also made a `datetime` object with lubridate and have arranged the DF with `fct_reorder` according to the hour of `Datetime`. This allows then to plot `Visit` in desired order.

All functions I have used belong to the `tidyverse`: `lubridate` for date formatting, `formats` for reordering and `ggplot`. It is possible to change the DF with pipes `|>` and to feed this so changed DF to the call to `ggplot`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df |> 
  mutate(Datetime = lubridate::as_datetime(Datetime)) |> 
  mutate(Visit = fct_reorder(Visit, hour(Datetime))) |> 
  mutate(Patientnum = as.factor(Patientnum)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Visit, y = SBP, color = Patientnum, group = Patientnum)) + 
  geom_point(shape = "square", size = 2) + 
  geom_line(linetype = "solid", size = 1)
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]

---

**Data**:

```
Datetime <- c("2018-07-20 15:04:00", "2018-09-04 13:30:00",
              "2021-08-31 08:20:00","2021-09-06 12:36:00")
Visit <- c("SCR H15", "C1D1PRE H13", "C1D1PRE H8", "C1D1HR2 H12")
Visitnum <- c(1,2,2,3)
Patientnum <-  c(1, 1, 2, 3)
SBP <- c(115, 120, 130, 127)

df <- data.frame(Datetime, Visit, Visitnum, Patientnum, SBP)
```

Comment: Hi MarBlo, I strongly appreciate your help. But I want "C1D1PRE H8" to appear before "C1D1PRE H13". because when considering a larger data, the Hour 8 measurements for SBP are taken before measurements at Hour 13. Can the code be modified to achieve this? Can we use any other variable from the data to arrange visits in such way?

Comment: @`Vaishnavi Kenjale`  I have made a new edit and ordered the axis according to the hour of `Datetime`.